# Is it possible to lookup an EJB from JAX-WS resource?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jax-ws, jboss7.x, lookup

I have an ear file deployed in jboss 7. It contains a JAX-WS resource class that look up an EJB.
But the EJB lookup fails and it throws exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling

When I remove `@WebService` annotation, EJB lookup works fine. Can anyone tell me whether it is possible to lookup an EJB from JAX-WS resource?

Comment: Have you tried to add the `@Stateless` annotation to your webservice?

Comment: Yes, @WebService can be treated as EJB bean or CDI bean. How do you look up?

Comment: Please provide some additional information. How does your look-up look like?

Comment: My lookup code is as follows

Comment: `Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(props);
ReportServiceIF reportService = (ReportServiceIF) ic.lookup("ejb:reportService/reportServiceEJB//ReportServiceBean!com.service.report.ReportServiceIF");`